# Showing tautology ((q and(p implies ~q)) implies ~p)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Im having difficulty with this. Ive been able to go from

((q and(p implies ~q)) implies ~p) to 
~(~p and q) or ~p

Not sure whats next. Can I get some help please.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! If you write your questions using [*MathJax*](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), they are much more readable and that can help in the number of responses. Regards

Comment: (a->b) <=> (~b->~a) so that in your case, (p->~q) <=> (~(~q)->~p) <=> (q->~p) so that you basically have q && (q->~p) therefore ~p.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to show that the following is a tautology. There are five example techniques, however, the last one is just a kind of teaser.

$$q \land(p \implies \neg q) \implies \neg p$$

**1.** Brute-force checking, there are only 2 variables, so only $4 = 2^2$ possibilities to check.

**2.** Use the fact that
$$\alpha \implies \beta \quad \text{ is equivalent to } \quad \neg\alpha \lor \beta $$
and then expand
$$ \neg(q \land (\neg p \lor \neg q)) \lor \neg p$$
and simplify the formula using De Morgan laws
$$ \neg(q \land \neg (p \land q)) \lor \neg p$$
$$ \neg q \lor (p \land q) \lor \neg p$$
$$ (p \land q) \lor \neg p \lor \neg q $$
$$ (p \land q) \lor \neg (p \land q) $$

**3.** Use the contrapositive statement, that is

$$\alpha \implies \beta \quad \text{ is equivalent to } \quad \neg\beta \implies \neg \alpha $$

for example

$$q \land(p \implies \neg q) \implies \neg p$$
$$q \land(q \implies \neg p) \implies \neg p$$

and conclude that it is a tautology by using [*modus ponens*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens).

**4.** Use the fact that the only way

$$q \land(p \implies \neg q) \implies \neg p$$

could fail is when $p$ is true. However, $p \implies \neg q$ equals then $\neg q$ and the premise could be simplified to $q \land \neg q$ which is obviously false and thus the whole implication holds.

**5.** Use [Curry-Howard isomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry-Howard_correspondence), that is rewrite

$$q \land(p \implies \neg q) \implies \neg p$$

into this type

$$q \times (p \to (q \to \bot)) \to (p \to \bot)$$

and prove by providing an element

$$\lambda \langle q, f \rangle.\ \lambda p.\ f\ p\ q$$

of the required type and thus showing that it is inhabited.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

$$(q~\wedge(p\to\sim q))\equiv(q~\wedge(\sim p\vee \sim q))\equiv(q~\wedge\sim p)\vee(q~\wedge\sim q)\equiv (q~\wedge\sim p)\vee F\equiv q~\wedge\sim p$$ and so $$(q~\wedge(p\to\sim q))\to\sim p\equiv~ \sim(q~\wedge\sim p)\vee\sim p\equiv\sim q$$ Do the same calculation for RHS and see $\sim q\to\sim q$.

Comment: One of my favorite domains: logic! +1

Answer (score 0):

Use deMorgan's law to say $\sim(\sim p $ and $ q) \equiv p $ or $ \sim q$

Answer (score 0):

There are only 4 possible assignments to $(p,q)$. Check that the two formulae match for each assignment.